# Why doesn't Clementine pick up track information when ripping CD?

Tags: music, cd

I just started using [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org) and it seems to recognize the CDs correctly if I open them to play, and populates all of the album and track names correctly.

But if I use

> Tools -> Rip audio CD

I just have 'track 1, track2' etc. And I have to go through the ripped files afterwards to get track information, which is time consuming, and often not with the right tracks/album combination available from the lookup.

If it can recognize the CD correctly to play it, why doesn't it name the ripped files?

What am I missing?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but perhaps you might try using Sound Juicer to rip your audio CDs if you cannot figure out how to get the desired results from Clementine.

Comment: In addition to the above, if I copy the .wav files off the CD into a temporary folder, and then select all and `Edit track information -> Complete tags automatically`, Clementine gets a different set of sometimes inaccurate track titles and album names. The album names are often from a variety of albums, whereas using the open to play functionality, it knows that it has a single album.